# Login and Registration using in .NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-1.1, password-hash, usermanager

I am implementing Authentication and Authorization Role base in Asp.Net Web API Core 1.1 . I am using JWT token for generating token and authenticating the request but i am stucking to match the username and password with the existing database default generated tables by Identity. How to match password with PasswordHash and Register new user. Is the any example to implement Login and Registration api in .Net Core 1.1?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UserManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1) to create new user with method 
`public virtual Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(TUser user, string password)`
and 
 [SignInManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1) to sign in with given password using method:
`public virtual Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(TUser user, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)`

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody]UserModel model)
    {

        IdentityResult result;

        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.UserName };

             result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (! result.Succeeded) return  BadRequest(ModelState);

        return Ok(new {userCreated=true, userName= model.UserName });
    }

 [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]UserModel loginViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var userFound = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginViewModel.UserName);

            if (userFound == null) return Unauthorized();

            var userId = userFound?.Id;

            // Claims, we endow this user
            var claims = new[]
            {

            new Claim(Helpers.Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Id, userId),
            new Claim(Helpers.Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, Helpers.Constants.Strings.JwtClaims.ApiAccess),
            new Claim("test2", "test2")
         };


            // Get options from app settings
            var options = _configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));

            SymmetricSecurityKey _signingKey =  new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration["SecretKey"]));

            // Configure JwtIssuerOptions


            var token = new JwtSecurityToken
            (
                issuer: options[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)],
                audience: options[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)],
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60), // token works 1 hour! (then invalidates)
                notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(_signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            );

            return Ok(new { token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token) });
        }

        return BadRequest();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Login and Registration in .Net MVC by calling .Net Web API

Front End .Net MVC

```cs
private readonly string _apiBaseUrl = "https://localhost:7284";

public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAction([Bind("username,password")] UserLogin userLogin) {
  string apiUrl = $"{_apiBaseUrl}/login/username={userLogin.username}/password={userLogin.password}";
  HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl);
  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
    var token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
  } else {
    ViewBag.Message = "Username or Password is Inncorrect";
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
  }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterAction(UserMaster userMaster) {
  string apiUrl = $"{_apiBaseUrl}/api/UserMaster/register";
  var client = new HttpClient();
  var data =
      new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userMaster),
                        System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "Application/Json");
  var response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, data);
  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
  } else {
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Registration failed");
    return View();
  }
}
```